# ColdFusion won't start after applying the 9.0.1 update How do I roll it back?

Tags: coldfusion

I installed the Coldfusion 9.0.1 update and now The application server won't start. I'm concerned that I may have installed the 64 bit update on a 32bit server but I am not sure how to check it without a running CF instance.

When trying to start the CF9 service I get the following error:

> "Windows could not start the ColdFusion 9 Application Server on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2."

The Event log entry states:

> "The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service could not be started. Check the server "coldfusion" log files for more information."

The last server log entry is from when I stopped the service before installing the update:

> "Information","Thread-1","03/12/13","17:04:09",,"ColdFusion stopped"

My coldfusion logs don't seem to list any errors. The installation log claims that it was successfully installed.

At any rate I'd like to simply roll back the update but I'm unsure how to do that. I have a `C:\ColdFusion9\updater_backup` folder do I just drag the contents of that folder into the root directory in order to restore the previous version?

Comment: What ColdFusion update are you talking about - specifically?  The update page at Adobe usually mentions the rollback steps. Just navigate to the update page at Adobe and follow those steps.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this log file:

```
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\coldfusion-out.log
```

I saw a bunch of lines which read

```
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

old jvm.config file:

```
java.home=C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre
```

Changing it to:

```
java.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre
```

Comment: Coldfusion update installer also makes a backup of the jre before installing the update. I just edit jvm config file and changed to:
`java.home=C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre_installerbackup`

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for us:

> To resolve this, copy `msvcr100.dll` from `{JDK Home}\jre\bin` to
>   `{ColdFusion-Home}\runtime\bin`.

Try that.  If it still fails

> To uninstall the Cumulative Hotfix:
>
> - Stop the ColdFusion instance.
> - Delete the chf9010004.jar file at {ColdFusion-Home}/lib/updates. Revert to the backed up jar files mentioned in the Step 6 of the
>     installation instructions above.
> - Revert to the backed up CFIDE, WEB-INF and lib directory files, mentioned in the Steps 7, 9 and 11.

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-4-coldfusion-901.html

Comment: He's talking about the 9.0.1 update, not the latest hot fix. At least that's what his post sounds like, and that theirs no bit specific patch for chf4.

Comment: Busches is correct. 

thanks for the suggestion though. didn't seem to work. Maybe something else is going on here. I'm going to have to reinstall it looks like